# How to make first button not active when click on second button

Tags: jquery, button, hyperlink

In jquery, I have two buttons with unique id's, one is set to active, with a class of class="active" - how do i write a jquery... when I click on the second button that is not active, remove the active class of the first button

Answer (score 1):

If there are no siblings other than the two buttons:

```
$("#btn1, #btn2").click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("active"))
    {
        $(this).siblings("button").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```